# How to print dictionary with array value without any brackets or quotes?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that has *character* keys and *list* values.

```py
my_dict = {
    'A': [1, 1, 0, 0], 
    'B': [0, 0, 1, 1], 
    'C': [1, 1, 1, 0], 
    'D': [1, 0, 0, 0]
}
```

When I simply print it using `print(my_dict)`, I get an output like this:

```
{'A': [1, 1, 0, 0], 'B': [0, 0, 1, 1], 'C': [1, 1, 1, 0], 'D': [1, 0, 0, 0]}
```

What I want is this:

```
A: 1 1 0 0
B: 0 0 1 1
C: 1 1 1 0
D: 1 0 0 0
```

How can I do this without making it complicated?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of writing very complicated code for single line solution, create a for loop for *(key, value) pairs* in the dictionary.

Simplest way to do it is:

```py
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    print(str(key) + ":", *value)
```

Comment: Or `print('f{key}: {" ".join(value}')`

Comment: @rv.kvetch - You are free to answer the question if you have a better solution. Stackoverflow gives the option to answer your own questions to share any knowledge. Read this if you still find it suspicious - [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).